# Using buttons on different views and classes to trigger view switch from the main view controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, delegation

I am using storyboard to create my page.. each with it's own class... from the mainViewController, I manage the view change with a swipe gesture recognizer... So far so good... But I have certain pages that will appear as "popup" when swiping up and to get rid of them, the user clicks on the X to remove the view... the thing is that doing this and releasing the view from superview is giving me a white screen as the switch is not done by the mainViewController, since the view is release by the popup class... I think I need to use some sort of delegation to do this.. but my brain just doesn't want to sink in how to use the delegate thing, even after reading about it...

Since the view switching is done on index 1, i'd figure that if I put those popup on index 2 and release them, the view at index 1 would still be there, but.. no..
... so at the beginning of my swipe gesture function, I start declaring the animation process... then I have a switch...case that check for the gesture being done.. left will set the animation to curlUP and right to Curl down... this is what happens after the switch... I also put ***myView*** into a ***myViewTemp***, and add the new view to ***myView*** in the switch..case statement..

```
      if (myView.title == @"popup1") {
        [myView viewWillAppear:YES];
        [myViewTemp viewWillDisappear:NO];

        //     [myViewTemp.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:myView.view atIndex:2];

        [myViewTemp viewDidDisappear:NO];
        [myView viewDidAppear:YES];
        }     else {
                  [myView viewWillAppear:YES];
                  [myViewTemp viewWillDisappear:YES];

                  [myViewTemp.view removeFromSuperview];
                  [self.view insertSubview:myView.view atIndex:1];

                  [myView viewDidDisappear:YES];
                  [myViewTemp viewDidAppear:YES];
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        }
```